# KNN algorithm implementation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, knn

I'm creating my own implementation of KNN. Although everything seems to be working, the accuracy I get is quite poor compared to KNN from sklearn (for example 0,68 vs 0,96 tested on a few sets). I also use 5-fold cross validation. The most important part of my code is as follows:

```
def knn(X, y, Z, k):
    mod_lst = []
    for i in range(Z.shape[0]):
        distance = []
        for j in range(X.shape[0]):
            distance.append(np.linalg.norm(X.iloc[j] - Z.iloc[i]))
        mod_lst.append(modde(distance,y,k))
    return mod_lst

def modde(ret,y,k):
    '''sorting distances in ascending order'''
    dic = {i: ret[i] for i in range(0, len(ret))}
    dic1 = {r: v for r, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
    ind = [dic1.keys()]

    a = list(dic1.keys())
    '''sorting y (labels) in ascending order'''
    d = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(a,y))]

    d = d[:k]
    d = list(map(int, d))
    modw = statistics.mode(d)

    return modw
```

Where:

```
k = 5
X - training set (data, a nxm matrix of points in R^m)
y - training set (labels, 1xn array of zeros, ones, etc)
Z - testing set
```

**Why do my results differ with scikit-learn implementation results?**

Comment: This will be hard to answer unless we know what the dataset is and can test your code on it. Are you able to provide a fully-working example with training and test data that we can download and run locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite hard to answer your question. First of all, Scikit-learn implementation has runtime optimization and contains an elaborate implementation.

The implementation of KNN (classifier) is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/neighbors/_classification.py#L25). I recommend you read the implementation since the new github read-code feature is enabled and it is easy to follow the implementation of the library.

For example, check [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c42d54b26137a456c510c5fdba1ba23e0/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py#L705) how they define the distance graph. You will notice their code differs a little bit from yours.

Also, scikit-learn uses the scipy library to compute some of the metrics, for example, the distance of points is built over the [scipy pdist() function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist).